# Making a list of every separate line with jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, text

I'd love to know that how to create a list from block of text. Let me explain..

Here's my html:

```
<div class="asd">
well
worth
it
</div>
```

And this should be automatically converted to list like this:

```
<div class="asd">
<ul>
<li>well</li>
<li>worth</li>
<li>it</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Hope you understood :-D I've already tried it with various methods but I'm not familiar with jQuerys element-functions yet.

Martti Laine

Comment: curiuos too, is a line of text (separated by a linebreak) capturable via jquery...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$(".asd").each(function() {
    var list = $("<ul>").insertBefore(this);
    var lines = $(this).remove().text().split("\n");
    list.append($.map(lines, function(str) {
        return $("<li>").text(str).get(0);
    })); 
});
```

You might want to add some kind of check for empty lines, though.